# django create count subquery without groupby

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I want to use a query that could be used as subquery. But I noticed that query like this:

```
x = Deal.all_objects.filter(state='created').values('id').annotate(cnt=Count('id')).values('cnt')
```

produces

```
SELECT COUNT("deals_deal"."id") AS "cnt" 
FROM "deals_deal" 
WHERE "deals_deal"."state" = created 
GROUP BY "deals_deal"."id"
```

I don't need the `GROUP BY`, I just want to count offers that match filter.

I don't want to use `.count()` because It would not let me to write a query like this:

```
Deal.all_objects.filter(
            Q(creator=OuterRef('pk')) | Q(taker=OuterRef('pk'), state='completed')
        ).annotate(cnt=Count('pk')).values('cnt')
```

How to modify above query so that it count without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: what is `annotate(cnt=Count('id'))` supposed to do? This is always 1 because you're counting a column of the row itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is done with aggregate not annotate.

```
x = Deal.objects.filter(state='created').values('id').aggregate(cnt=Count('id'))
# x is a dictionary {"cnt":9000}, you wouldn't even need the ".values('id')" now
```

This will result in a query something like this

```
SELECT COUNT("deals_deal"."id") AS "cnt" 
FROM "deals_deal" 
WHERE "deals_deal"."state" = created
```

Further cool things you can do with [Aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)